# How to populate request parameters into a Plug.Conn connection?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm trying to test a method that receives a connection of type [Plug.Conn](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#functions) but I don't find a way of initializing the connection with the request parameters with the `Plug.Conn` API.

E.g:

```rb
test "put request params", %{conn: conn} do
  # put %{"foo" => "bar"} into the connection params

  assert conn.params == %{"foo" => "bar"}
end
```

Is there any way to set those parameters in the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're doing something special in your `MyAppWeb.ConnCase` setup that you want to use here, the easiest way would be building a new conn with [`Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#build_conn/3) (or [`Plug.Test.conn/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Test.html#conn/3) if you aren't using Phoenix):

```rb
test "put request params" do
  conn = build_conn(:get, "/", %{"foo" => "bar"})

  assert conn.params == %{"foo" => "bar"}
end
```